# Open filled-form page in ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm using [mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) to fill out a form, but I want to review it on the webpage before submission. The goal is to open a browser with the pre-filled form.

```rb
require 'mechanize'

mechanize = Mechanize.new
page = mechanize.get('https://www.linuxtoday.com/contribute.html')

form = page.form_with :name => 'upload'
form.sub_name = "mbb"
form.email = "mbb@mbb.com"
form.author_name = "Mr Potatohead"
form.title = "Mr Potatohead writes Ruby"
form.link = "https://potato.potato"
form.body = "More text"

`open #{page.uri}`
```

Calling out to the operating system to open the site is, of course, empty form. I don't see a `page.open` or similar method available. Is there a way to achieve this (using mechanize or other gems)?

Comment: Not with Mechanize, and not by opening a URL. Think of it this way: When you fill out the form in your browser, is any of the information you enter captured in the URL? If you fill out the form and then copy the URL and paste it in another tab, is the information you entered preserved? In the case of this and most other web sites, no, and the same is case when you use Mechanize. If you want to fill out a form in a browser window, you'll need to use something like Webdriver or Chrome's Puppeteer protocol, which direct the browser itself to perform actions.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that @JordanRunning. I am asking to break the client-server connection while getting around the fact I can't parameterize interactions through an API. Maybe I'll review them interactively from the command-line instead of in the browser... the gotcha would be working around the captcha.

Comment: For this you may want to make a simple [Electron](https://electronjs.org) app.

Comment: selenium is like mechanize but uses a real browser (headless or visual). You can put a "wait' call in the script to pause until you fill in the captcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments try selenium, you'll need chrome or firefox driver installed, here's example with chrome to get you started:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'pry' # optional

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

driver.navigate.to 'https://www.linuxtoday.com/contribute.html'
form = driver.find_element(id: 'upload')
form.find_element(id: 'sub_name').send_keys 'mbb'
form.find_element(id: 'email').send_keys 'mbb@mbb.com'

binding.pry # or sleep 60 
driver.quit
```

For more instructions [see documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings)

Comment: This looks to be the most helpful choice and gives me a browser to edit it in. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That won't work because setting form fields doesn't even update the DOM.

If you want to review the form data you can inspect `form.request_data`